# What :a, ba mean in "sed -e :a -e '$d;N;2,5ba' -e 'P;D' file"?

Tags: sed

I understand that final result of

`sed -e :a -e '$d;N;2,5ba' -e 'P;D' file`

I don't understand what `:a, ba` mean. Also I get confused why `-e` is specified 3 times?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-e` specifies a sed script of which there are 3.

```
:a
```

is a label for use with b and t commands.

```
$d;N;2,5ba
```

means match the last line and delete. The next input line is appended into pattern space. For lines 2, 5 we'll branch to label `:a`.

Last script prints pattern space up to the first newline, and deletes up to the first newline in the pattern space.

Comment: So let me get it straight: -e:a is label "declaration", then sed goes to delete last line. But how does it count backwards from 2 to 5 from the end. Isn't count goes from top?  Thank you.

Comment: Ok! I read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12833714/the-concept-of-hold-space-and-pattern-space-in-sed and I think I got it. Thank you very much for your answer, hexafraction