# awk/sed grep between two patterns and obtain what is between them, is this possible?

Tags: sed, awk

I need more help in this case, to do something similar to a grep between two patterns: 
I need to look for Everyone Allow  FullControl

Say I have this:

```
    Path   : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::\\eiesc1\Service_Legal 
    Access : BUILTIN\Administrators Allow  FullControl
    -----------------------
    Path   : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::\\eiesc1\balco 
    Access : Everyone Allow  268435456
             Everyone Allow  FullControl
    -----------------------
    Path   : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::\\eiesc1\BCDRPlanning 
    Access : Everyone Allow  FullControl
             Everyone Allow  268435456
    -----------------------
```

so I would get something similar to this:

```
    Path   : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::\\eiesc1\balco 
             Everyone Allow  FullControl
    -----------------------
    Path   : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::\\eiesc1\BCDRPlanning 
    Access : Everyone Allow  FullControl
```

I did not know how to do this so I come here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `sed`

```
sed -nr '/-{3,}/h; /Path\s*:/H; /Everyone\s+Allow\s+FullControl/{x;G;p}' file
```

Output:

```
    -----------------------
    Path   : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::\\eiesc1\balco
             Everyone Allow  FullControl
    -----------------------
    Path   : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::\\eiesc1\BCDRPlanning
    Access : Everyone Allow  FullControl
```

**Short Description**

```
sed -nr '
    /-{3,}/h;            # if '---' pattern is found in a line, copy it to hold space
    /Path\s*:/H;         # if 'Path  :' pattern is found in a line, append it to hold space
    /Everyone\s+Allow\s+FullControl/{x;G;p}    # if 'Everyone Allow  FullControl' pattern is found in a line, 1) exchange Pattern and Hold space, 2) Append pattern space to hold space and 3) print pattern space.
' file
```

Here we make use of *Pattern Space* and *Hold Space* manipulator of `sed`

Snippet from `man sed`

```
   h H    Copy/append pattern space to hold space.   
   g G    Copy/append hold space to pattern space.
   x      Exchange the contents of the hold and pattern spaces.
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Incredible how easy you make it seem, could you explain me a little the syntax?

Comment: @Eduardo Added short description. Please check.

Comment: @Eduardo Glad that it worked for you! Some more references: [SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12834372/526471), [Examples for Sed Hold and Pattern Buffer Operations](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/12/unix-sed-tutorial-7-examples-for-sed-hold-and-pattern-buffer-operations/)

Answer (score 2):

You can do some like this with `awk`

```
awk '/Everyone Allow/ && /FullControl/' RS="-" file

    Path   : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::\\eiesc1\balco
    Access : Everyone Allow  268435456
             Everyone Allow  FullControl


    Path   : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::\\eiesc1\BCDRPlanning
    Access : Everyone Allow  FullControl
             Everyone Allow  268435456
```

To restore separator:

```
awk '/Everyone Allow/ && /FullControl/' RS="-" file | awk '/[0-9]+/ && /Everyone/ {next} $0=="" {$0="-----------------------"}1'
-----------------------
    Path   : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::\\eiesc1\balco
             Everyone Allow  FullControl

-----------------------
    Path   : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::\\eiesc1\BCDRPlanning
    Access : Everyone Allow  FullControl
```