# what does "h command" mean in bash?

Tags: bash, sed

when using sed like this in bash, below message was returned.

```
bash-3.2$ sed -i 's/\t/ /g' hoge.txt

sed: 1: "hoge.txt": extra characters at the end of h command
```

I understand that I need a suffix to work this command. But, I couldn't find meaning of "h command". What does it mean ?

Comment: The complaint is coming from `sed`. Possibly relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12833714/the-concept-of-hold-space-and-pattern-space-in-sed

Comment: It was a very helpful reference. Thanks !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `-i` parameter to sed takes an argument, so what you think is your sed command is actually the backup filename suffix for the in place edit. Then `hoge.txt` is being taken as the command to run, hence the error about the `h` command.

The correct way to do this would be `sed -i '' -e 's/\t/ /g' hoge.txt`

Using `-e` isn't strictly required, but by passing it you ensure that sed will treat the next token as the command.

Comment: To expand on this, note that GNU `sed` allows an optional argument for `-i` while BSD `sed` requires an argument. The reference to `bash` 3.2 in the prompt suggests Mac OS X, which uses BSD `sed`.

Comment: Thank you for your very plain explanation !