# unix sed substitute nth occurence misfunction?

Tags: bash, sed

Let's say I have a string which contains multiple occurences of the letter Z.
For example: `aaZbbZccZ`.
I want to print parts of that string, each time until the next occurence of Z:

```
aaZ
aaZbbZ
aaZbbZccZ
```

So I tried using unix sed for this, with the command `sed s/Z.*/Z/i` where i is an index that I have running from 1 to the number of Z's in the string. As far as my sed understanding goes: this should delete everything that comes after the i'th Z, But in practice this only works when I have i=1 as in `sed s/Z.*/Z/`, but not as I increment i, as in `sed s/Z.*/Z/2` for example, where it just prints the entire original string. It feels as if there's something I am missing about the functioning of sed, since according to multiple manuals, it should work.

edit: for example, in the string `aaZbbZccZ` while applying `sed s/Z.*/Z/2` I am expecting to have `aaZbbZ`, as everything after the 2nd occurence of Z get's deleted.

Comment: post the expected result

Comment: The first occurence matches up to the end of the string, there's no second occurence left to match.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you want to use `sed` for this job? Particularly if you're operating on a string variable as opposed to a file, this is arguably a job for shell-builtin string primitives.

Comment: With awk: `echo 'aaZbbZccZ' | awk -F 'Z' 'END{OFS=FS; c=NF; line=$0; for(i=1; i<c; i++) {$0=line; NF=i; print $0 OFS}}'`

Answer (score 2):

Below sed works closely to what you are looking for, except it removes also the last Z.

```
$echo aaZbbZccZdd | sed -e 's/Z[^Z]*//1g;s/$/Z/'
aaZ

$echo aaZbbZccZdd | sed -e 's/Z[^Z]*//2g;s/$/Z/'
aaZbbZ

$echo aaZbbZccZdd | sed -e 's/Z[^Z]*//3g;s/$/Z/'
aaZbbZccZ

$echo aaZbbZccZdd | sed -e 's/Z[^Z]*//4g;s/$/Z/'
aaZbbZccZddZ
```

Edit:
Modified according to Aaron suggestion.

Edit2:
If you don't know how many Z there are in the string it's safer to use below command. Otherwise additional Z is added at the end.
`-r` - enables regular expressions
`-e` - separates `sed` operations, the same as `;` but easier to read in my opinion.

```
$echo aaZbbZccZddZ | sed -r -e 's/Z[^Z]*//1g' -e 's/([^Z])$/\1Z/'
aaZ

$echo aaZbbZccZddZ | sed -r -e 's/Z[^Z]*//2g' -e 's/([^Z])$/\1Z/'
aaZbbZ

$echo aaZbbZccZddZ | sed -r -e 's/Z[^Z]*//3g' -e 's/([^Z])$/\1Z/'
aaZbbZccZ

$echo aaZbbZccZddZ | sed -r -e 's/Z[^Z]*//4g' -e 's/([^Z])$/\1Z/'
aaZbbZccZddZ

$echo aaZbbZccZddZ | sed -r -e 's/Z[^Z]*//5g' -e 's/([^Z])$/\1Z/'
aaZbbZccZddZ
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you expect (see comments) unless your string can contain line breaks:

```
# -n will prevent default printing
echo 'aaZbbZccZ' | sed -n '{
    # Add a line break after each 'Z'
    s/Z/Z\
/g
    # Print it and consume it in the next sed command
    p
}' | sed -n '{
    # Add only the first line to the hold buffer (you can remove it if you don't mind to see first blank line)
    1 {
        h
    }
    # As for the rest of the lines
    2,$ {
        # Replace the hold buffer with the pattern space
        x
        # Remove line breaks
        s/\n//
        # Print the result
        p
        # Get the hold buffer again (matched line)
        x
        # And append it with new line to the hold buffer
        H
    }'
```

The idea is to break the string into multiples lines (each is terminated with `Z`), that will be processed one by one on the second `sed` command.

On the second `sed` we use the [Hold Buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12834372/61824) to remember previous lines, print the aggregated result, append new lines and each time remove the line breaks we previously added.

And the output is

```
aaZ
aaZbbZ
aaZbbZccZ
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -n 's/Z/&\n/g;:a;/\n/P;s/\n\(.*Z\)/\1/;ta' file
```

Use sed's grep-like option `-n` to explicitly print content. Append a newline after each `Z`. If there were no substitutions then there is nothing to be done. Print upto the first newline, remove the first newline if the following characters contain a `Z` and repeat.