# how can i improve my sed command to extract data form ping log file?

Tags: bash, sed

Follow the details, the site is asking me to include some text because there is mostly code, so i type this sentence, but i think it is self explanatory

Sample log file :

```
jue 08 abr 2021 13:33:49 -03 : VA  John Doe  : PING google.com (17x.2xx.1x2.4x): 56 data bytes

--- google.com ping statistics ---
100 packets transmitted, 100 packets received, 0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max = 40.462/50.166/62.318 ms
jue 08 abr 2021 13:35:35 -03 : VA  John Doe  : PING google.com (17x.2xx.1x2.4x): 56 data bytes

--- google.com ping statistics ---
100 packets transmitted, 99 packets received, 1% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max = 42.055/48.856/136.962 ms
jue 08 abr 2021 13:37:21 -03 : VA  John Doe  : PING google.com (17x.2xx.1x2.4x): 56 data bytes

--- google.com ping statistics ---
100 packets transmitted, 100 packets received, 0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max = 40.058/47.762/64.169 ms
```

my command so far :

```
cat sample.log | sed -r -e '/^... [0-9]+ ... [0-9]{4} [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}/{s/(... [0-9]+ ... [0-9]{4} [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}).*$/\1/g;n;d}' -e '/^--- google.*$/d' -e 's/100 packets transmitted.*([0-9]+%) packet.*$/\1/' -e '/round-trip/d'
```

result obtained :

```
jue 08 abr 2021 13:33
0%
jue 08 abr 2021 13:35
1%
jue 08 abr 2021 13:37
0%
```

desired ideal result :

```
jue 08 abr 2021 13:33, 0%
jue 08 abr 2021 13:35, 1%
jue 08 abr 2021 13:37, 0%
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's assume:

- The packet loss percentage is always found in lines ending with `NUM% packet loss`.
- The date and time are always found in lines ending with `data bytes`.

Then, with GNU sed (tested on the two complete records you show):

```sh
$ sed -nE '/packet loss$/{s/.*\s([0-9]+%) packet loss$/\1/;h}
  /data bytes$/{s/(.{24}).*/\1/;G;s/\n/, /;p}' sample.log
jue 08 abr 2021 13:35:35, 0%
jue 08 abr 2021 13:37:21, 1%
```

Comment: thanks, i like the look of that. Reading man to figure out what h and G command do and what are pattern space and hold space ...

Comment: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12833714/the-concept-of-hold-space-and-pattern-space-in-sed#12834372) is quite clarifying about pattern and hold spaces. 
Now I am wondering if the new line within the expression can be replaced by some other character  @renaud-pacalet ?

Comment: In the sed script I suggest the newline character is replaced by `, ` (comma-space). Replace it by anything else if it is not what you want.

Comment: i was referring to the newline before the 2nd 'address' (or whatever sed calls it), that is '/data bytes$/'. I induced it was to separate from the first one and realized that replacing it with a semicolon worked all the same. 
I needed it in one line to be able to copy/paste it easily.

Comment: Oh! Sorry, I misunderstood your question. Yes, sed commands can be separated by newlines or by semicolons.

Answer (score 2):

***1st solution:*** This should be a task for `awk`. With your shown samples, please try following `awk` code.

```
awk -v OFS=", " '
match($0,/^[a-zA-Z]+ [0-9]{2} [a-zA-Z]+ [0-9]{4} ([0-9]{2}:){2}[0-9]{2}/){
  val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH-3)
  next
}
/packets transmitted/{
  print val,$(NF-2)
  val=""
}
'  Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Simple explanation would be, using `match` function where mentioning regex to match `^[a-zA-Z]+ [0-9]{2} [a-zA-Z]+ [0-9]{4} ([0-9]{2}:){2}[0-9]{2}`(explained regex in further), if a match of is found then creating val variable which has value of matched(caught value) by regex. Using `next` will skip all further statements from here. Then checking condition if line contains `packets transmitted` then print val along with 3rd last field of that line. Nullifying `val` variable then.

***Explanation of regex:***

```
^[a-zA-Z]+               ##Matching small/capital letters 1 or more occurrences from starting.
 [0-9]{2}                ##Matching space followed by 2 occurrences of digits.
 [a-zA-Z]+               ##Matching space followed by 2 occurrences of small/capital letters.
 [0-9]{4}                ##Matching space followed by followed by 4 digits.
 ([0-9]{2}:){2}[0-9]{2}  ##Matching space followed by digits 2 occurrences followed by colon and this whole group should occur 2 times followed by 2 occurrences of digits.
```

---

---

***2nd solution:*** Using GNU `awk` here we can use almost same mentioned regex in RS variable and can get desired results as follows:

```
awk -v RS='[a-zA-Z]+ [0-9]{2} [a-zA-Z]+ [0-9]{4} [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{1,3}%' -v OFS=", " '
RT{
  val=(val?val (++count%2==0?ORS:OFS):"") RT
}
END{
  print val
}
'  Input_file
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, i am not familiar with awk, but i just tried it and didn't get my desired result ... got a mix of x% only lines and other lines with date time aside x% seperated by space ...

Comment: @mrossw, with your shown samples, both of my answers/solutions worked fine for me. Is your actual Input_file same as shown samples?

Comment: @mrossw,  Also make sure you don't have carriage returns in your file, try running command `cat -v your_file` once if you see control M characters in it then you need to remove them before running my codes.

Answer (score 0):

To get the desired format, you can pipe the output to:

```
sed 'N;s/\n/, /'
```

The final command becomes (note that you don't need to cat to sed as it accepts the filename as an argument):

```
sed -r -e '/^... [0-9]+ ... [0-9]{4} [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}/{s/(... [0-9]+ ... [0-9]{4} [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}).*$/\1/g;n;d}' -e '/^--- google.*$/d' -e 's/100 packets transmitted.*([0-9]+%) packet.*$/\1/' -e '/round-trip/d'  sample.log | sed 'N;s/\n/, /'
```

**Output**:

```
jue 08 abr 2021 13:33, 0%
jue 08 abr 2021 13:35, 1%
jue 08 abr 2021 13:37, 0%
```

Comment: thanks, this gets me what I need. I was hoping some optimization for the expression.