# removing a line and the line before it

Tags: linux, sed, grep, data-processing

i'm trying to remove the lines containing literal ,32, and the line BEFORE/ABOVE it that should always contain ,34,

```
files example:
dd,34,dd 10:00 game1
dd,32,dd 10:01 game1
dd,34,dd 12:30 game2
dd,31,dd 12:32 game2 
dd,34,dd 13:54 game3
dd,31,dd 13:55 game3
dd,34,dd 15:00 game1
dd,32,dd 15:00 game1
```

#note: there's a few thousand of these lines in the file

I've tried using grep
`grep -v -B1 ',32,'`file1 > file2

file2 should be all lines from file1 except for the lines containing ,32, and the line before ,32,
doesnt work as intented

`sed "/\,32\,/,+1d" rp1 > rep2`
`sed "/\,32\,/,~1d" rp1 > rep2`
deletes lines in a different order than intended. The amounts of lines containing ,34, match the lines containing the rest of the symbols. As if it deletes the ,32, line and the line AFTER instead of BEOFRE.

OUTPUT AFTER USING SED command from above:

```
dd,34,dd 10:00 game1
dd,31,dd 12:32 game2 
dd,34,dd 13:54 game3
dd,31,dd 13:55 game3
dd,34,dd 15:00 game1
```

DESIRED OUTPUT:

```
dd,34,dd 12:30 game2
dd,31,dd 12:32 game2 
dd,34,dd 13:54 game3
dd,31,dd 13:55 game3
```

Comment: Try `sed '1,/32/d' file1` and let me know if this is what you are expecting

Comment: @GauravPathak, thank you for the reply. I've looked up what the command you've send me does and it isnt what I was expecting due to me not explaining the situation in full detail.

The file contains XXXX amounts of lines looking like the ones in the examples. Once every 2 lines there's a line containing ,34,. The other half of the lines containts either a range from 30-32. 

I've edited the post for clarity

Comment: Found it hard to understand what you want, to understand more can you share the output you want based on the input you shared

Comment: @SelVazi i've added the desired output to posts description

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the desired output you need to understand [The Concept of 'Hold space' and 'Pattern space' in sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12833714/the-concept-of-hold-space-and-pattern-space-in-sed)
Please refer the above URL to get an understanding.

You can use the following `sed` command to get the desired output:

```
sed -n '/,32,/{s/.*//;x;d;};x;p;${x;p;}' inputFileName | sed '/^$/d'
```

The above command will delete all the lines matching `,32,` pattern and the line exactly above/before it.

The above command is storing every line in a buffer called as **hold space**, when `sed` encounters the pattern which is `,32,` it deletes the content of **pattern space** i.e. current line as well as **hold space** i.e. the previous line.

Hope this answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

Using any awk plus tac:

```
$ tac file | awk '/,32,/{c=2} !(c&&c--)' | tac
dd,34,dd 12:30 game2
dd,31,dd 12:32 game2
dd,34,dd 13:54 game3
dd,31,dd 13:55 game3
```

If you wanted to delete blocks of, say, 5 lines instead of blocks of 2 lines, you'd just change `c=2` to `c=5`.

See [Printing with sed or awk a line following a matching pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17908555/printing-with-sed-or-awk-a-line-following-a-matching-pattern) for an explanation for that awk script and similar idioms.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -n 'N;/\n.*,32,/d;P;D' file
```

Open a two line window.

If the second line contains `,32,`, delete both lines.

Otherwise, print/delete the first and re-establish the two line window.